# How can I redirect the output of an exec() system call from stdout to a pipe and read the result into a buffer from the parent process?

Tags: c, ipc

The goal is to have the cksum_child function create a child process, and execute the checksum command on the provided file. Redirecting the output to a pipe and reading the result from the pipe in the entry function get_cksum which is functioning as the parent.

`

```
pid_t
create_cksum_child (int *pipe, char *const filename)
{
  pid_t pid = fork();

  if (pid < 0) {
    printf("fork\n");
    return NULL;
  }

  if (pid == 0) {
    close(pipe[0]);
    dup2(pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    execlp("/usr/bin/cksum", "cksum", filename, NULL);
    printf("execlp\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  int status;
  waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

  return pid;
}

char *
get_cksum (char *const filename)
{
  char *buffer = NULL;

  int fd[2];
  if (pipe(fd) < 0) {
    printf("pipe\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  pid_t child_pid = create_cksum_child(fd, filename);

  if (child_pid == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  fflush(stdout);

  ssize_t bytes_read = read (fd[0], buffer, sizeof (buffer));

  close(fd[0]);
  close(fd[1]);

  if (bytes_read < 1) {
    printf("bytes read: %ld\n", bytes_read);
    return NULL;
  }

  return buffer;
}
```

`

The code I have here closely follows my textbook sections on IPC models, which initially caused a timeout err. From what I've gather from similar questions on SO I needed to fflush() stdout since the output was being buffered which fixed the timeout but the returned string is incorrect. I then added print statement to see how many bytes I'm reading from the pipe and I get -1 bytes on all test files.

What mistakes did I make and what can I do to redirect the output from stdout and read it in the parent properly?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you should merge the 2 functions together because the parent code is not only in the second function but it is splitted into both functions you wrote.

For example you should move the waiting lines

```
int status;
waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
```

on the parent side, since the parent has to wait the child and not vice versa.

After that, your code is in a good shape but probably you should refactor it after the merge of the functions.